# Forms autosave question

Tags: c++, qt

I am making an application in c++ and qt and i am wondering how i can autosave my forms instead of pressing the save button everytime. Since i have never done it before,i am thinking autosave is only for the web.What is the best way to approach this?.

Comment: You mean while you are closing the application you want everything to be saved?

Comment: say you are editing one form field and you are done.If you move the cursor outside the field you were editing,the form field you were editing get saved.

Comment: In user applications, usually you apply the changes when the user presses OK or Apply. That's custom code one has to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. A `QTextBox` will not lose its value suddenly, only when it's destroyed. And unless you arrange it otherwise, that doesn't happen before the destructor of the form finishes. So you can always get the textbox content, even from the destructor.